# Why polars on intel cpu is faster than on amd cpu?

Tags: python, intel, python-polars, amd-processor

I have two pc, one is Intel i7 13700KF with 64GB RAM and another is AMD 3970X with same RAM, both pc use ssd as storage and both pc has python 3.11 and polars 0.20.5. I run code below:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["a"+str(i) for i in range(1000000)],
    "age": [i for i in range(1000000)]
})
```

```py
%%timeit
df.with_columns([
    pl.col("name") + "test",
    pl.col("age").rolling_mean(20)
])
```

And I find intel get `12.9 ms ± 20.8 µs per loop` while amd get `24.8 ms ± 270 µs per loop`

The cpu benchmark is close for these two cpu. Why there is such big difference?

Also I found when you do a little calculation on Apple M3 Max, it could be beaten by intel i7 13700KF, but when you do a lot of polars work like 20-30x `with_columns`, M3 Max would beat intel i7 13700KF.

Comment: I think you better raise an issue to the developers of polars: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues

Comment: Also, since it's a Threadripper, you might want to set the Core Affinity for Python so that threads don't cross over to a different CCX. Remember that TR 3970X architecture is 4 x 2 x 4 (CCD, CCX per CCD, core per CCX). Anytime a thread crosses the CCX boundary, latency will increase. And if the thread gets shunted to a different CCD, latency increases significantly. Pegging Python to run only on cores within the same CCX gives the minimum latency.

Comment: Thank you @pepoluan, I tried to use `multiprocessing` to limit the core, but it is not faster